# Refresh: make the browser use the files in cache

Tags: php, image, caching, browser, refresh

The situation is the next:

1. I have a php page with a few images that are repeated continuously.
2. These images are served dynamically but in differents positions (I guess it has nothing to do with my problem).
3. I don't want the browser to download the images each time the page is updated-refreshed.

EDIT: I tried headers but it doesn't work. Although I'm not sure if I did right, I put the header ('header("Expires: Sat, 1 Jul 2016 00:00:00 GMT");') at the begining of the main page (My images have 'standard' urls and they are served like icons).

So my solution was reduce the size of these images but it's not enough. I was very grateful if someone help to solve this problem. Thank you in advance.

Comment: You need to set an `Expires`header in the future.  Either configure on the webserver or output from the PHP file if it delivers the image,

Comment: I tried headers but it doesn't work. Although I'm not sure if I did right, I put the header at the begining of the main page (My images have 'standard' urls). Thanks again.

Comment: No the header needs to be sent with the image.